# How to add an Image in Veusz?

Tags: ubuntu, latex, gnuplot, veusz

How do I import an image (.png,.jpg) in Veusz such that I superimpose it on an existing plot.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean an image file (e.g. JPG or PNG), then click on `Insert->Shape->Imagefile`. In the properties window, click `..` to the right of `Filename`. Find your image file.

(PS remember to accept answers to your previous questions).

Comment: Is it possible to add an eps image? I am having a difficult time getting the resolution of png and jpg files right.